# ngModel radio buton miss behaving

Tags: radio-button, angular8, ngmodel

I am having issues with radio button with ngModel when I am populating with ngFor

1. Radio button selection is misbehaving
2. In the console.log of Form, i see the value of gender is "it"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUh3D.png)

What am I doing wrong
Here is my code

```
app.component.ts 

gender :string[] = ["Male", "Female"];

app.component.html

<div class="radio" *ngFor="let it of gender">
   <label><input ngModel type="radio" name="gen"  value="it">{{it}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly donot post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after playing around, issue is with the 'value' of radio button, it has to be property binded

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let it of gender">
   <label><input ngModel type="radio" name="gen"  [value]="it">{{it}}</label>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let it of gender">
   <label><input ngModel type="radio" name="gen"  value={{it}}>{{it}}</label>
</div>
```